# Why is the model not displayed?

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I'm trying to implement multi-model model loading, but my loaded models are not displayed. My code is identical to this code https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewmodels/tree/nodejs,the only difference is in the ForgeViewer.js file, where I use the code from this article https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/02/model-aggregation-with-view-data-api-exposed.html. 
When writing function launchViewer (token, urn) I get this "GET error https://developer.api.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/manifest/undefined?domain=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000 400 (Bad Request)", and without adding token, I do not get an error, but the models are not displayed. The oss.js file is completely identical to the file from the first article.

Below is the code for the ForgeViewer.js file.

```
function launchViewer(urn) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {

      var options = {
        env: 'AutodeskProduction',
        getAccessToken: getForgeToken
      };
      console.log(options);
      Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, () => {
        Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(
          'urn:' + urn,
          (document) => {
            var rootItem = document.getRootItem();

            var geometryItems3d = Autodesk.Viewing.Document.
            getSubItemsWithProperties(
              rootItem, {
                'type': 'geometry',
                'role': '3d'
              },
              true
            );

            var geometryItems2d = Autodesk.Viewing.Document.
              getSubItemsWithProperties(
              rootItem, {
                'type': 'geometry',
                'role': '2d'
              },
              true
            );

            var got2d = (geometryItems2d && geometryItems2d.length > 0);
            var got3d = (geometryItems3d && geometryItems3d.length > 0);

            console.log(options);
            console.log(document);
            console.log(rootItem);
            console.log(geometryItems2d);
            console.log(geometryItems3d);
            console.log(got2d);
            console.log(got3d);

            if (got2d || got3d) {
              var pathCollection = [];
              geometryItems2d.forEach((item) => {
                pathCollection.push(document.getViewablePath(item));
              });

              geometryItems3d.forEach((item) => {
                pathCollection.push(document.getViewablePath(item));
              });

              return resolve(pathCollection);
            } else {

              return reject('no viewable content')
            };
          },
          (err) => {
            console.log(options);
            console.log('Error loading document... ');
            //Autodesk.Viewing.ErrorCode
            switch (err) {
              // removed for clarity, see full sample
            }
          });
      });
    } catch (ex) {
      return reject(ex);
    }
  });
}

function getForgeToken(callback) {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/api/forge/oauth/token',
    success: function (res) {
      callback(res.access_token, res.expires_in)
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you successfully and completely translate the model (see tutorial [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/prepare-file-for-viewer/)) and supply a based64 encoded object ID (e.g. `var urn = btoa('urn:adsk.a360betadev:fs.file:business.lmvtest.DS5a730QTbf1122d07')`) of the model to the load method?

```
 Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(
          'urn:' + urn, //The base64 encoded object ID of your translated model object goes here
...
```

Without it the urn part in your manifest request from your error message would be `undefined` and hence the error.

Comment: I deleted the equal sign at the end of the urn, but my models are still not displayed. I can understand what the problem is.

[image](https://www.screencast.com/t/WcESgSA1t)

Comment: There is no error, an error occurs only when I write function launchViewer (token, urn) instead of function launchViewer (urn)